# highcharts xAxis yearly data

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

Trying to got temp data from 1895 and upward to display on highcharts. The issue is that the xAxis is incorrect. How do I get this to display correctly (tick for each year increasing to the right)?

```
$('.cchighchart').highcharts({
chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
},
title: {
    text: null
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: 'Average Temperature (F)'
    }
}],
series: [{
    name: 'Average Temperature',
    width: 3,
    zIndex: 1,
    yAxis: 0,
    data: [
        ["1895", 42.441666666667],
        ["1896", 44.875],
        ["1897", 44.033333333333],
        ["1898", 42.716666666667],
        ["1899", 43.183333333333],
        ["1900", 45.408333333333],
        ["1901", 45.116666666667]
    ]
}]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/deadpickle/ZAqzj/

Comment: exactly thanks for the catch

Comment: If you are going to use the `datetime` type then you need to convert the year to unix epoch time. But I don't think you actually need this to be a `datetime` axis. See http://jsfiddle.net/ZAqzj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `datetime`, you need your x-axis data to be in unix epoch time. This can be done fairly simply like this:

```
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(1895, 0, 1), 42.441666666667],
        [Date.UTC(1896, 0, 1), 44.875],
        [Date.UTC(1897, 0, 1), 44.033333333333],
        [Date.UTC(1898, 0, 1), 42.716666666667],
        [Date.UTC(1899, 0, 1), 43.183333333333],
        [Date.UTC(1900, 0, 1), 45.408333333333],
        [Date.UTC(1901, 0, 1), 45.116666666667]
    ]
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAqzj/2/)

Alternatively, if you don't actually really need this to be a `datetime` axis (which if all you data is yearly, you really don't), you can just remove the `type` from your `xaxis` and change your years to numbers (rather than strings) and it will plot just fine:

```
    data: [
        [1895, 42.441666666667],
        [1896, 44.875],
        [1897, 44.033333333333],
        [1898, 42.716666666667],
        [1899, 43.183333333333],
        [1900, 45.408333333333],
        [1901, 45.116666666667]
    ]
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZAqzj/1/)